# printing the entire row with particular given last column criteria

Tags: perl

Input:

```
orf00007                    PHAGE_Prochl_MED4_213_NC_020845-gi|472340344|ref|YP_007673870.1|              7665 8618 0.210897481636936
orf00007                    PHAGE_Prochl_MED4_213_NC_020845-gi|472340344|ref|YP_007673870.1|              7665 8618 0.210897481636936
orf00007                    PHAGE_Prochl_P_HM2_NC_015284-gi|326783200|ref|YP_004323597.1|             7665 8618 0.207761175236097
orf00015                    PHAGE_Megavi_lba_NC_020232-gi|448825467|ref|YP_007418398.1|           11594 13510   0.278721920668058
orf00015                    PHAGE_Acanth_moumouvirus_NC_020104-gi|441432357|ref|YP_007354399.1|           11594 13510   0.278721920668058
```

The script I had implemented:

```
use feature qw/say/;
use Math::Trig;

open FILE,"out02.txt";
my @file=<FILE>;
close FILE;
my $aa=0;
for(my $i=$aa; $i <=17822; $i++){
    if (($file[$i]>=0.210)){
        open(OUTFILE,'>>OUT_t10-t10.txt');
        print OUTFILE $file[$i];
    }
    else{}
}
```

Note:

1. I need to take the last column as the analysing criteria to print the entire row(the float value, eg:0.210897481636936)
2. for example if the user input value is '0.210',it has to produce >= values rows ,the expected output is

Output:

```
orf00007                    PHAGE_Prochl_MED4_213_NC_020845-gi|472340344|ref|YP_007673870.1|              7665 8618 0.210897481636936
orf00007                    PHAGE_Prochl_MED4_213_NC_020845-gi|472340344|ref|YP_007673870.1|              7665 8618 0.210897481636936
orf00015                    PHAGE_Megavi_lba_NC_020232-gi|448825467|ref|YP_007418398.1|           11594 13510   0.278721920668058
orf00015                    PHAGE_Acanth_moumouvirus_NC_020104-gi|441432357|ref|YP_007354399.1|           11594 13510   0.278721920668058
```

Answer (score 0):

A script like the following could work for you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

die "Usage: $0 number file\n"
    if @ARGV != 2;

my $minval = shift;

while (<>) {
    my @cols = split;
    print if $col[-1] >= $minval;
}
```

And execute it like:

```
perl yourscript.pl 0.210 out02.txt >> OUT_t10-t10.txt
```

Or using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'print if $F[-1] >= 0.210' out02.txt >> OUT_t10-t10.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk -v value=0.210 '$NF >= value' file
```

Or

```
awk -v value=0.210 '$NF >= value' file > output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This scripts (inspired on yours) solves the problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $user_filter = 0.21;

open my $input_file, "<", "out02.txt" or die $!;   # Modern way of open files
open my $output_file, ">>", "OUT_t10-t10.txtt" or die $!;

while( my $line=<$input_file> ) {
    if( $line =~ / ([\d\.]+)\s*$/ ) {
        # If a number was found at the end of line
        if( $1 > $user_filter ) {  # Check condition
            print $output_file $line;  #Write to output file
        }
    }

}

close $input_file;
close $output_file;
```

Comment: it produces just a blank file as output

Comment: I have tested, and it works fine for me. Does the file out02.txt exists in the same path as this script?